# Mocking ngResource in Angular unit tests

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have an `ngResourceMockFactory` which looks like this:

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular.module('app')
    .factory('NgResourceMock', ngResourceMockFactory)
  ;

  ngResourceMockFactory.$inject = [];

  function ngResourceMockFactory() {
    function NgResourceMock() {
      var context = this;

      context.$promise.then = function() {
        context.prototype.$promise.then.apply(context, arguments);
      };

      context.$promise.finally = function() {
        context.prototype.$promise.finally.apply(context, arguments);
      };
    }

    NgResourceMock.prototype.$promise = {
      then: function(onSuccess, onError) {
        this.$promise.onSuccess = onSuccess;
        this.$promise.onError = onError;
      },
      finally: function(onComplete) {
        this.$promise.onComplete = onComplete;
      }
    };

    return NgResourceMock;
  }
})();
```

I inject this into my tests in a `beforeEach` like so:

```
beforeEach(inject(function(NgResourceMock) {
  ngResourceMock = new NgResourceMock();
}));
```

then I use it like this:

```
describe('initiateWorkflow function', function() {
  beforeEach(function() {
    vm.player = {id: 123};
    spyOn(dataService, 'initiateWorkflow').and.returnValue(ngResourceMock);
    vm.initiateWorkflow();
  });

  it('should call dataService.initiateWorkflow', function() {
    expect(dataService.initiateWorkflow).toHaveBeenCalledWith({playerId: vm.player.id}, {});
  });
});
```

but I keep seeing the following error:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'context.prototype.$promise')
```

This leads me to believe that something is wrong with my `ngResourceMockFactory`, but I'm not sure what it is.

Comment: context is just an instance of NgResourceMock ,so `context.prototype` is undefined , you should use `NgResourceMock.prototype` instead. it just solve this error. for mocking you can use [this tutorial](https://scotch.io/tutorials/testing-angularjs-with-jasmine-and-karma-part-1)

Answer (score 4):

Don't know if this can be of any help, but if you are trying to evaluate asynchronous operations in your tests, you may want to use the `done()` method in Jasmine.

As per their documentation:

```
beforeEach(function(done) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      value = 0;
      done();
    }, 1);
});
```

by passing `done` as a parameter of the `beforeEach` callback, any test run after the before each will wait until the `done()` function has been called.

Source: [Jasmine](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html) (Asynchronous Support section).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution to your problem.

The error `TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'context.prototype.$promise')` is caused when you try to invoke the promise object before invoking the function into which it is defined or into which your parent function is defined.

Here the `returnValue(ngResourceMock)` is directly calling into the function without the context and parameters need to be defined.

Therefore you can try to add another  `beforeEach` statement like

```
beforeEach(angular.mock.module(app));
```

to load your app module

Here may be the same concept related to your problem [another link here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21948459/how-do-i-mock-the-result-of-a-promise-in-an-angularjs-unit-test)

Hope it may help you a bit.